# Python win32com : Reading multiple Outlook inbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I want to get the SenderEmailAddress of all email sent on two specified mail addresses : 123@abc.com and 456@def.com that are in my Outlook Application on my computer, the point is to make a list of all mail senders that will be kept in a csv file.

The architectures of these mailboxes are this way :

123@abc.com

- -> Inbox

&

456@def.com

- -> Inbox

I would like to read the Inbox Folders from the two mailboxes and store the SenderEmailAddress from the two Folders

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

I've found that for some people it works to use

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[1] # To access 123@abc.com Inbox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[2] # To access 456@def.com Inbox
```

But in my case it just gets me inside of the two subfolders that are inside of Inbox and nothing more, I don't have the possibility to access at all to the second mailbox.
I have the possibility to detect these Mailboxes by using

```
for folder in outlook.Folders: 
    print(folder.Name)
```

I have no idea how to fix this and finally access to my second mail address, if anyone would be capable to help me on this it would be great.

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That happens because `GetDefaultFolder(6)` is referencing to the first `Inbox`, thus `.Folders[1]` and `.Folders[2]` will only get you to the subfolders of that same first `Inbox`.

You can access those inboxes by specifying them like this:

```
inbox = outlook.Folders('123@abc.com').Folders('Inbox') # To access 123@abc.com Inbox
inbox = outlook.Folders('456@def.com').Folders('Inbox') # To access 456@def.com Inbox
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! I thought that GetDefaultFolder(6) was for getting into 'Inbox', I didn't know that I had to use Folders twice, thanks a lot for your answer man !

Comment: For anyone who finds this after me it appears the format for referencing folders/subfolders has updated to `inbox = outlook.Folders['123@abc.com'].Folders['Inbox']`